# du -s | cut -d' ' -f2 -- cut having no effect

Tags: linux, bash, cut

I'm trying to get the size of a specified file only. Normally I have zero issues doing this, but no matter what I try here the filename does not go away.

```
[root@dockertest Shipper]# du -s c_parser.py | cut -d ' ' -f 2
8   c_parser.py
```

Nothing changes based on what I put after the pipe. Changing '2' to '1' doesn't do anything. Using:

```
[root@dockertest Shipper]# du -s c_parser.py | awk -F="c_parser.py" '{ print $1 }'
```

Does nothing at all either. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can get the file size with `stat -c "%s" file`

Comment: `du c_parser.py | cut -f1` should do the job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `du` is tab-separated, you need to use tab delimiter. Though tab is the default delimiter in `cut`, you could also use it explicitly

```
du -s file | cut -d $'\t' -f2
```

or just

```
du -s file | cut -f2
```

In such cases, do a `hexdump` of the output will help you understand easily

```
du -s file | hexdump -c
0000000   8  \t   f   i   l   e  \n                                    
0000007
```

Using `awk` too on tab-delimiter

```
du -s file | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{print $2}'
```